# Improving "Other" Flag text for uniformity in close vote comments

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, custom-close-reasons

For questions like this (not calling out, it's just recent and an apt example)  . .

[How can I read faster?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/23004/how-can-i-read-faster)

. . and comments like these . .

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not related to interpersonal skills.

. . which:

- vary user-to-user
- and are non-informative about where to look for help on on-topic questions
- and have to be typed out every single time,

. . can we edit the text in "Other" flag to something better ?

**Current text:**

- Other (add a comment explaining what is wrong)

  > I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because

**Possible text:**

- Other (add a comment explaining what is wrong)

  > I'm voting to close this question because it is off-topic for the site as per the policies mentioned in [help/on-topic].

The [help/on-topic] will help while commenting in markdown.

See the answer for improvement for the same.

P.S. I am avoiding tag [feature-request](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) intentionally. It's too hot to handle.

Comment: How often would this close reason actually this be used? I don't have time right now to go through the close stats myself, but we have a limited number of slots for custom close reasons, so I'd rather not use one up if this doesn't happen often..

Comment: Actually I may have misunderstood your intent - if you mean changing the pre-filled text in the free-form text box, we would need a SE employee to do that, mods can only add new (static text) reasons.

Comment: yup the question got a major update recently. And yes I read about the custom flag limits. and yes to SE employee too :p

Answer (score 1):

I was the one that made that comment, and I simply used the format given in the "other" reason, and there really isn't much to say on that question. "other" option gives us a nice format of "I am voting to close this question as off topic because...." so that we can just fill in the blank there. I have no idea where the question could be asked as well.

What I'm trying to say is that the "other" close reason is already a nice custom close reason that people can fill in the blank for individual cases.

Comment: Okay so in the same old good "Other", would you like better text?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm voting to close this question because it is off-topic for the site as per the policies mentioned in [help/on-topic].

Comment: "*maybe the current text in "other" flag can be changed from...*": by default, it is. But we can still modify it. I'll (most of the time) do it because it doesn't fit what I need to convey, and I find it too *raw* (and even close to "rude" sometimes). What you're actually asking is: `we modify the default text so we have less to edit?`

Comment: in this answer, yes. Also, that's what I indicated in the last line. `people would have to delete`. I know that it is editable and they have to edit it to fit their needs. It can be made a bit better.

Comment: @OldPadawan in case you drop by in the chatroom.. [I can decide off-topic and close vote or reopen questions on IP\[S\], not on Apple](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51797366#51797366) Which means, I saw two different banners and caused some confusion.